# Nested If-Else Checkup Requested

Tags: nested

I am tasked with writing a nested branch that follows the following pattern:

```
        * if numberCups is greater 1 AND less than or equal to MAX_CUPS:
        *   print numberCups + " is a valid number of cups!"
        *
        * else:
        *   print numberCups + " is a not valid number of cups!"
        *   print "Please enter another number of cups between 1 and 100: "
        *   numberCups = scnr.nextInt();
        *
        *   if numberCups is greater 1 AND less than or equal to MAX_CUPS:
        *       print numberCups + " is a valid number of cups!"
        *
        *   else if numberCups < 1:
        *       print numberCups + "is less than 1. Sorry you are out of" 
        *       attempts."
        * 
        *
        *   else
        *       print numberCups + "is greater than 100. Sorry you are out  of attempts."
```

This is my code so far:

```
if (numberCups > 1 && numberCups <= MAX_CUPS) {
           System.out.println(numberCups + " is a valid number of cups!");
       }
       else {
           System.out.println(numberCups + " is a not valid number of cups!");
       }

       System.out.println("Please enter another number of cups between 1 and 100: ");
          numberCups = scnr.nextInt();

          if (numberCups > 1 && numberCups <= MAX_CUPS) {
              System.out.println(numberCups + " is a valid number of cups!");
          }
          else if (numberCups < 1) {
              System.out.println(numberCups + "is less than 1. Sorry you are out of attempts");
          }
          else {
              System.out.println(numberCups + "is greater than 100. Sorry you are out of attempts");
          }
```

Can someone take a quick look over this code and let me know if it confirms to the requirement and whether I have something incorrectly above? I'm new at all this and would appreciate the recommendation and check up. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should post here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/